# Retrieving error messages from Zend InputFilter

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

```
$app->post('/', function () use ($app) {

    $email = new Input('email');
    $email->getValidatorChain()
          ->addValidator(new Validator\EmailAddress());

    $password = new Input('name');
    $password->getValidatorChain()
             ->addValidator(new Validator\StringLength(1));

    $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
    $inputFilter->add($email)
                ->add($password)
                ->setData($_POST);

    if ($inputFilter->isValid()) {

        // do stuff

        $app->redirect('/');

    } else {

        $field_errors = array();

        foreach ($inputFilter->getInvalidInput() as $field => $error) {
            foreach ($error->getMessages() as $message) {
                $field_errors[] = str_replace('Value', ucfirst($field), $message);
            }
        }

        $app->render('index.php', array('field_errors' => $field_errors));

    }
});
```

I currently have the above code using the Slim Framework and using Zend InputFilter. However, I want to retrieve the error messages. I keep getting 'Value ....' so I did a `str_replace` on them to get `Email is not a valid email` like below:

```
        $field_errors = array();

        foreach ($inputFilter->getInvalidInput() as $field => $error) {
            foreach ($error->getMessages() as $message) {
                $field_errors[] = str_replace('Value', ucfirst($field), $message);
            }
        }
```

Is this the right way to get error messages from Zend InputFilter or is there anything else?

Comment: I was just thinking if there's a better way since it's been my first time to use this component.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to call $inputFilter->getMessages() to get a keyed array back:

```
array(
    'input' -> 'message', 
    'inputtwo' => 'anothermessage',
);
```

this internally uses getInvalidInput() for you so there's no need to have those nested foreach loops, a single call to getMessages() should be fine.